# IE trouble jquery height of iframe

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, height

i have the following line to control the height of an iframe from within its content:

`$("#frame",top.document).height($("#frame",top.document).contents().find("html").height());`

it works perfect until someone uses IE.. how can i get it to work with IE?

thanks in advance,
Ello

found a solution:

```
var iFrame = parent.document.getElementById('frame');
newHeight = parseInt(iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight)+20;
$("#frame",top.document).height(newHeight);
```

Comment: What version of IE? And what is the nature of your problem?

Comment: it was with ie 7 to 9, however the above works :)

Comment: Ello, please post the solution as an answer and accept it! I almost overlooked it - I wouldn't look for a solution in a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, tomas, her we go:

```
var iFrame = parent.document.getElementById('frame');
newHeight = parseInt(iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight)+20;
$("#frame",top.document).height(newHeight);
```